Plotting multi-dimensional array values in Flutter FlCharts
I'm trying to plot the array received from an API into FlCharts but I'm not able to correctly iterate over the second level.
My array is as follows. I'm currently testing with static sample values which I'll replace from actual response later. I have full control over the API that's sending the values so please suggest if I should optimize the array structure.
 var listData = [
    {
      'Product01': [12.0, 14.5, 15.6, 12.1, 15.2, 17.6, 12.8, 24.0, 35.4, 12.9]
    },
    {
      'Product02': [9.0, 12.5, 11.6, 7.1, 10.2, 14.6, 8.8, 18.0, 31.4, 10.9]
    },
  ];

The code I'm trying is as below:
var sections = listData.asMap().entries.map((data) {
      final idx = data.key;
      final listval = data.value;

      return LineChartBarData(
        spots: listval.asMap().entries.map((item) {
          FlSpot(item.key, item.val);
        }).toList(),
        color: chartColors[idx],
        barWidth: 5,
        isCurved: true,
        dotData: FlDotData(show: true),
      );
    }).toList();

and in the chart view
AspectRatio(
   aspectRatio: 1.30,
         child: LineChart(
                  LineChartData(
                    lineBarsData: sections,
              ),

The error I get is
lib/modules/home/widgets/yearly_expenses.dart:106:24: Error: The method 'asMap' isn't defined for the class 'Map<String, List<double>>'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'asMap'.
        spots: listval.asMap().entries.map((item) {
                       ^^^^^

I tried several variations (map, forEach) but none seems to work. I'm totally new to Dart coming from PHP. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Edit: I updated my code as below, still get errors.
List sections = listData.asMap().entries.map((data) {
      final idx = data.key;
      final listval = data.value;

      listval.entries.map((entry) {
        final k = entry.key;
        final v = entry.value;

        return LineChartBarData(
          spots: v.asMap().entries.map((data) {
            return FlSpot(data.key, data.value);
          }).toList(),
          color: chartColors[idx],
          barWidth: 5,
          isCurved: true,
          dotData: FlDotData(show: true),
        );
      }).toList();
    }).toList();


This time the error is
Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<LineChartBarData>'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'LineChartBarData' is from 'package:fl_chart/src/chart/line_chart/line_chart_data.dart' ('.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/fl_chart-0.69.0/lib/src/chart/line_chart/line_chart_data.dart').
                    lineBarsData: sections,
                                  ^


You have missed some important thing, when converting an existing List to Map, each item is associated to auto-incremented integer key so that your list will become like the following:
{
  1 :{
      'Sales': [12.0, 14.5, 15.6, 12.1, 15.2, 17.6, 12.8, 24.0, 35.4, 12.9]
    },

  2 :{
      'Cost': [9.0, 12.5, 11.6, 7.1, 10.2, 14.6, 8.8, 18.0, 31.4, 10.9]
    },

}

You have treated the key correctly, but you forgot that the data associated with the key is itself an encapsulated Map (Nested Map), so, it has its own key and value.
so to access that list :
listval = data.value['Sales'];
listval = data.value['Cost'];


I still get errors. I guess I may not have explained it clearly with my example. I wish to make it generic, so instead of Sales and Cost, I changed to Product01 and Product02 to bring more clarity. In this case I would not know how many products but each of them will become a line on the chart. Can you see what I'm trying to do?

@Ravi, yes i'm in the loop (i know what you need to do). but there's a question, what are the parameters and their type of the Flspot() method?   if it's an integer and a list of values to be drawn as a line. you will call it like this Flspot(item.key, item.value['Product01']) but notice that we are accessing the list through it's key Product01 so for the next item the key will be Product02.

I want to access it dynamically. The FlSpot() is coming from the FlCharts: https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/main/repo_files/documentations/bar_chart.md. I have updated the question with my latest code which still has errors.
